# How to RestrictBlank Spaces In An Input Field In This Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I believe it's a new request from what I've seen here. I'm using `onkeyup()` on one `input` to append and create a new value in a second `input`. It works great but I want to restrict white/blank spaces in the second `input`. See [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXeRvb) here

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="fullnames" onkeyup="createUsername();" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">

<!--restrict blank space-->
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
```

**Script**

```
    function createUsername() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fullnames").value;
    document.getElementById("username").value= x;
}
```

**Final result**

This is how it should be

```
Full Names : John Doe 
Username : johndoe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` and `String.prototype.toLowerCase` methods:

```js
var name = ' John Doe ';
var username = name.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();

console.log(username);
```

Btw be aware that there can be more characters that you might want to handle too. For example in my language we can have those in name `ěščřžýáíé` (plus their upper case variants).

See this gist for more advanced way that can handle those (it does slightly different thing - putting dashes instead of spaces, but its almost the same):

https://gist.github.com/Majkl578/947036

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function createUsername() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fullnames").value;
    x = x.trim() // gets rid of leading and trailing spaces
    var username = document.getElementById("username");
    username.value = x;
}
```